# mongodb find by subfield doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this query where I want to search by name of customer:

```
  var search = {}
  if ((req.query.from !== '' && req.query.from && req.query.from !== undefined && req.query.from !== 'undefined') || (req.query.to !== '' && req.query.to && req.query.to != undefined && req.query.to != 'undefined')) {
    search = {
      $and: [
        { date: { '$gte': ['$date', req.query.from] } },
        { date: { '$lte': ['$date', req.query.to] } }
      ]
    }
  }
  var namesearch = {}
  if (req.query.search && req.query.search != undefined && req.query.search != 'undefined') {
    namesearch =
      { "customer_id.name": new RegExp('^' + req.query.search, "i") }


  }
  // console.log(search);
  var data = await Schema.find({ $and: [{ deleted_at: null }, namesearch, search,] })
    .populate('creator')
    .populate('customer_id')
    .populate('seller_id')
    .populate('tel_id')
    .populate('product_id')
    .skip(parseInt(req.query.skip))
    .limit(parseInt(req.query.limit))
    .sort(req.query.sort)
    .exec();
  console.log('data ', { $and: [namesearch, search] });
  var count = await Schema.countDocuments({ $and: [{ deleted_at: null }, search] })
    .exec();

  if (data.length == 0) {
    res.json({ status: false, message: "Data not found" });
    return 0;
  } else {
    res.json({ status: true, count, data: data, message: "list employee sales" });
    return 0;
  }
```

this is the schema the query runs on:

```
created_at:"2022-11-07T11:34:17.431Z"
creator:"601ba89aed53f60be2799e72"
customer_id:"6360ad0ec312e0e5c418e44b"
date:"2022-11-07T00:00:00.000Z"
deleted_at:null
editor:"601ba89aed53f60be2799e72"
note:""
peshaky: 2
product_id:"635ffb94bacf79d322481567"
sales_price:11
seller_id: "63624d80c64ad541c2253e59"
seller_salary_is_paid: true
seller_share:2
tel_id: "63624d80c64ad541c2253e59"
tel_salary_is_paid: false
tel_share: 3
updated_at: "2022-11-07T11:38:50.234Z"
__v: 0
_id: "6368ed39e8c3f35a7e7cbf0a"
```

the customer_id is a reference from customers table and has name property. so I want to search based on customer name but this query doesn't return anything even when the data exists.